# I am writing Automating script for check box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing problem in writing automation script for check box for website, please go through website link and i am sharing my code please go through this code.

http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account

Please go through below screen shot Where i did red circle over check box, i want xpath for that.[image]

Comment: Please elaborate what seems to be the problem and include a stack trace of the error you are getting.

Comment: please open that website u will get account creation form, in that form two check box will comes, but m not able to click on that check box.

Comment: Please edit your question and make the following changes: remove your personal data from the code and replace it with fake data; add the error you receive when you try to run your code; and add comments to your code to explain what you are looking for in the absolute XPaths.

Comment: you can use the id for both those checkpoints! why you need xpath, but here you go //*[@id="optin"] and //*[@id="newsletter"]

Comment: What have you actually tried for an xpath or css selector? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 3):

I went through the URL provided by you. 
Here is the XPath for above two checkboxes:

1. Sign up for our newsletter!
   **XPath**: `//div[contains(@id,'uniform-newsletter')]/span[1]`
2. Receive special offers from our partners!
   **XPath**: `//div[contains(@id,'uniform-optin')]/span[1]`

Here is the **HTML** Code:

[image]

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Appreciate your answer i will check your code and soon come to you.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath:

> //input[@id='newsletter']

CSS

> input#newsletter

You can try out the below code to click. This code is in Java.

```
WebElement signUpNewsLetter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='newsletter']")); 
//You can check the state of the element
signUpNewsLetter.click();
//You can then check whether it's selected or not
boolean isSelected = signUpNewsLetter.isSelected();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the XPath for above both checkboxes.***

**Xpath 1. Sign up for our newsletter!**

`//*[@id="newsletter"]` or use below one

`/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[7]/label`

**Xpath 2.** **Receive special offers from our partners!**

`//*[@id="optin"]` or use below one

`/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div[1]/div[8]/label`

*I hope it is helpful to you.*